# Jenkins job on various dev versions?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have test.sh that I need run on

- python2.7/3.2/3.4
- falcon 0.1.10/0.2.0/latest
- ansible 1.4.4 /1.4.5/1.5.0/1.6.0/1.7.0/1.8.0/1.9.0

So I have a step_0 that install those dev envirement. But on one node I can have one version of dev envirement. So one instance of job must be run.

But I have 5 slaves where I can run test.sh with different params.

The behaviour that I need:

```
main job ----> runs  on: #Slave 1  test.sh (python2.7+falcon0.1.10+ansible 1.4.4)
[ main Node]             #Slave 2  test.sh (python2.7+falcon0.2.0+ansible 1.4.4)        
                         #Slave 3  test.sh (python2.7+falcon0.1.10+ansible 1.5.0)
                         #Slave 4  test.sh (python3.2+falcon0.1.10+ansible 1.5.0)
```

I have 4 slave Jenkins Nodes. I want run one instance of script on one Node but all this concurrent.

I created master Job: Multi-configuration project and Child Job that I run. But I can't achive needed behaviour.

### **Master job configuration:**

[image]

### **Child job:**

[image]

Regards.

Comment: *"invirement"* -> *"environment"*?

Comment: yes, sorry for my English

Comment: You've said you can't achieve the needed behaviour, but haven't made clear what that behaviour is, or what is going wrong. Why do there need to be separate master and child jobs? Why are you executing the matrix builds sequentially?

Comment: @Christopher Orr I have test.sh that I need run on python2.7/3.2/3.4 + falcon 0.1.10/0.2.0/latest + ansible 1.4.4 /1.4.5/1.5.0/1.6.0/1.7.0/1.8.0/1.9.0. So I have a step_0.sh that install those dev envirement. On one node for one test I can have one version of dev envirement. I need run test.sh concurrent on all slaves, but only one instance of it may be run in the same time. It's behaviour that I haven't achive.

Comment: You should update the question with this information. But still, running "concurrently" and only "one instance may run" is contradictory. If you mean only one build can run concurrently _per slave_, the easiest way to do that is to set the number of executors to one.

Comment: @Christopher Orr "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" I can't use it because For other kinds of jobs, allowing concurrent executions of multiple builds may be problematic, for example if it assumes a monopoly on a certain resource, like database, or for jobs where you use Jenkins as a cron replacement.